# How to concatenate `Object` with a string?

Tags: python, casting

How to concatenate `Object` with a string (primitive) without overloading and explicit type cast (`str()`)?

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text


_string = Foo('text') + 'string'
```

**Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
      _string = Foo('text') + 'string'

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'str'
```

operator `+` must be overloaded?
Is there other ways (just wondering)?

PS: I know about overloading operators and type casting (like `str(Foo('text'))`)

Comment: What is your expected result in _string? "textstring" ?

Comment: I want return a string. just wondering!

Comment: Why don't you want to use `str` to force the object into a string?

Comment: Python doesn't have casting. When you call `str`, you create a new string object by the return value of `MyType.__str__`. Casting is taking the same data in memory and telling the compiler/interpreter that it *is* another object type.

Comment: I'm just curious why `__ str__` doesn't return the string?

Comment: `__str__` _does_ return the string. But it isn't called when `+` is used, because python doesn't know what `+` means in this case. You have to tell it explicitly.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just define the `__add__()` and `__radd__()` methods:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
    def __add__(self, other):
        return str(self) + other
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return other + str(self)
```

They will be called depending on whether you do `Foo("b") + "a"` (calls `__add__()`) or `"a" + Foo("b")` (calls `__radd__()`).

Comment: IMO this is not good practice. Calling `str` explicitly is the correct pattern. Anyway, you're still calling `str` here, you're just hiding it.

Comment: @Daenyth, I think it depends on the circumstances. This isn't appropriate for any old object; but for something meant to emulate a string, it's perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @Daenyth: I agree with you, but there might be exceptions.

Comment: @senderle: The first thing I'd try to emulate a string is to derive from `str`.  Only if this is no option for some reason, I'd go with the approach above.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, yes, that's what I meant by "emulate." Perhaps I was being unclear; in my mind, a type that inherits from `str` is doing something more than "emulating" a string.

Answer (score 7):

```
_string = Foo('text') + 'string'
```

The problem with this line is that Python thinks you want to add a `string` to an object of type `Foo`, not the other way around.

It would work though if you'd write:

```
_string = "%s%s" % (Foo('text'), 'string')
```

**EDIT**

You could try it with

```
_string = 'string' + Foo('text')
```

In this case your `Foo` object should be automatically casted to a string.

Comment: Are you sure about your edit?  I'm pretty sure Python won't cast to string automatically.

Comment: @Constantinius, Thanx for the anwer, but I know about `type casting`. I want to understand how to return the real string from `__str__`

Comment: There's no such thing as Python casting objects to strings. Either the `__add__` method will do it explicitly or no one will do.

Comment: I thought of `'{}{}'.format(Foo('text'), 'string')` first. Maybe this is also an option...

Answer (score 1):

If that makes sense for your `Foo` object, you can overload the `__add__` method as follows:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    def __add__(self, other):
        return str(self) + other

_string = Foo('text') + 'string'
print _string
```

Example output:

```
textstring
```